# Using binding in DataTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm new to WPF and trying to figure out how to change the background color of a datagrid row based on the value of a column.  I've seen a few examples of people using datatriggers:

```
<DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding result}" Value="1">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding result}" Value="0">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
</DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

I can't figure out how the code side of this works.
I bind the `DataTable` to the `DataGrid` like this:

```
episodeDataGrid.DataContext = episodeTable.DefaultView;
```

Can I trigger the DataTrigger based on the text of one of the columns?  For example two rows:

Amount | result

4000  | 0

5000   | 1

The 4000 row  having the result value 0 will be green and the 5000 row having the result value 1 will be red?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataTable.DefaultView` is actually different than your data table.

Either, set the data context to the table itself :

```
episodeDataGrid.DataContext = episodeTable;
```

Or, adjust your binding :

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Row.result}" Value="1">
```